# How to iterate named checkbox that either returns a input element or a RadioNodeList?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

A search result can have from zero to many items. The search result/ the items are presented in a list with a checkbox for each item. All the checkboxes have the same name ("countrycode") and different values/IDs.

To get a named element I can use `e.target.countrycode` where the target is the form. Now, I would like to iterate all the checkboxes and make them checked, but the issue is that when there is only one search result `e.target.countrycode` returns the input element and when there are more `e.target.countrycode` returns a RadioNodeList.

What would be a good approach when I don't know if there is one or more items?

```js
document.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  for(const input of e.target.countrycode){
    input.checked = true;
  }
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="countrycode">Item 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="countrycode">Item 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="countrycode">Item 3</label>
  <label><button type="submit">Check all</button></label>
</form>

<form name="form02">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="countrycode">Item 1</label>
  <label><button type="submit">Check all</button></label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I `e.target.countrycode` has a length property it must be a RadioNodeList, otherwise the single element can be inserted into an array. In both cases the `inputs` is then iterable and can be used in the for loop.

```js
document.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let countrycode = e.target.countrycode;
  if (countrycode) {
    // if it has length then is must be a radionodelist
    let inputs = (countrycode.length) ? countrycode : [countrycode];
    for (const input of inputs) {
      input.checked = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="countrycode">Item 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="countrycode">Item 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="countrycode">Item 3</label>
  <label><button type="submit">Check all</button></label>
</form>

<form name="form02">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="countrycode">Item 1</label>
  <label><button type="submit">Check all</button></label>
</form>
```